# Does GCP MemoryStore support strong consistency?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm accessing MemoryStore from java/kubernetes using the 'lettuce' client. Can I expect a 'get' to be strongly consistent with GCP MemoryStore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memorystore for Redis isn't a distributed data store so you always query one single instance. There's no consistency issue in play.

For completeness, Memorystore for Redis offers 2 service tiers:

- Basic tier: provides a standalone Redis instance.
- Standard tier: Provides a highly available Redis instance that includes automatically enabled cross-zone replication and automatic failover. This means it provisions 2 instances, but the second one is just a replica of the first one for failover in case the master has an issue. However, you still only query on the master instance.